# Group and limit results for equal value columns

Tags: mysql

Have a table like this:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|  1   |  a   |
|  2   |  b   |
|  3   |  a   |
|  4   |  a   |
|  5   |  a   |
|  6   |  b   |
|  7   |  a   |
|  8   |  b   |
```

I would like to select rows randomly that have `a` and `b` but limit the result to 2 rows for each `a` and `b`, like this:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|  3   |  a   |
|  5   |  a   |
|  2   |  b   |
|  8   |  b   |
```

I'm probably missing something, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
select * from yourTable where col2 = 'a' order by rand() limit 2
union all
select * from yourTable where col2 = 'b' order by rand() limit 2;
```

Comment: add ORDER BY RAND() before the LIMIT to get random rows returned.

Comment: Something like this but i might have `c` or `d` to select also, should I just use unions or is there a better way?

Comment: @Arpi you could do it using variables, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results . Else the easiest is to use union if you don't have many datas. Note that I changed union to union all for better performance as we already know there won't be duplicates.

Comment: I will use union then, since it's much simpler than with variables. I might have max. 5 unions, which should not be a performance problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need also to use `ORDER BY RAND()`:

```
select * from yourTable where col2 = 'a' order by rand() limit 2
union
select * from yourTable where col2 = 'b' order by rand() limit 2;
```